# Energy cannot decent during optimization despite non-zero gradient

Tags: optimization, numerics

Assume we have an (at least) 2nd-order differentiable energy $f(x), x\in R^n.$ And $n$ is very big. Mathematically, I think it is impossible to find a point $\bar{x}$ where the energy cannot be decreased along its negative gradient when the gradient is not equal to zero. However, such kind of case can be occasionally found when an energy is optimized numerically, such as using the interior point method. In the optimization software, there is always a return code that describes that "the step size is too small and cannot make progress". Is it because of the numerical issues? Or is it that my mathematic conclusion is wrong? If it is from numerical issues, what kind of issue could lead to this problem?

Comment: Interior point methods imply constrained optimization. The optimal feasible point is not necessarily at a point with zero gradient.

Comment: @CharlieS The problem could be constrained optimization but it can also be unconstrained optimization. In this case, the interior point method degenerates to the Newton-Raphson method + line search, no barrier parameters and no Lagrangian multipliers. However, even in this case, the situation described above happens. So I didn't explicitly mention whether the problem is unconstrained or not.